# New instance of Var type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to make new instance of var types of variable in JavaScript?

For e.g.

```
var UserControl = { Id: '', Location: { Left: 0, Top: 0, Width: 0, Height: 0 }, Contents: '', Name: '' };
```

I wants to store this UserControl in JavaScript Array. Like below.

```
UserControl.Id = '1';
UserControl.Location.Left = offset.left;
UserControl.Location.Top = offset.top;
UserControl.Location.Width = offset.left + area.width();
UserControl.Location.Height = offset.top + area.height();
UserControlCollection.push(UserControl);
```

But UserControl overwrite previous entry because **UserControl** does not create new instance.

Any pointer for this?

Comment: you'd want something like `function UserControl () {}; var thisControl = new UserControl(); thisControl.id = "";`

Comment: jQuery is a utility library written in JavaScript. Your question has nothing to do with  jQuery, it is a plain javascript question. And it is not a JavaScript _Array_ but an _Object_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use function as constructor, like this

```
function UserControl() {
  this.Id = '';
  this.Location = {
    Left: 0, Top: 0, Width: 0, Height: 0
  };
  this.Contents = '';
  this.Name = '';
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/mimaha/1/edit?js,console)